# Get parameter in transformRequest

Tags: angularjs, android-resources

I use a REST Server API with angular $resource. I have no control over the Server API. The Server API requires that a list item has a property ItemTyp, which the list name with a Item appended. Which is redundant information

I would like to use the same resource for multiple lists and no. I tried following:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('mod', ['ngResource']);

    angular.module('mod').controller('Controller', function (ListItem) {
        var listItem1 = new ListItem({ a: 1 });
        listItem1.$save();

        var listItem2 = new ListItem({ b: 2 });
        listItem2.$save({ listName: 'list2' });
    });

    angular.module('mod').factory('ListItem', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/_api/lists/:listName/:Id', { listName: 'list1', Id: '@Id' },
            {
                save: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    transformRequest: function (data) {
                        //data.ItemTyp = listName + "Item";
                        return angular.toJson(data);
                    }
                }
            });
    });
})();
```

But I found no way to get the params in the transformRequest. Is there a way to get the params or a other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wrapper function to parse parameter into that object. Take a look at `someData`. Btw. you don't need to create a new object like `new ListItem()`.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('mod', ['ngResource']);

    angular.module('mod').controller('Controller', function (ListItem) {
        ListItem({ data: 'test'}).save({Id: 3, listName: 'testName'});
        ListItem({ data: 'test'}).save({Id: 4, listName: ''});
    });

    angular.module('mod').factory('ListItem', function ($resource) {
        return function (someData) {
            return $resource('/_api/lists/:listName/:Id',  { 
                    listName: '@listName', 
                    Id: '@Id' 
                }, {
                    save: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        transformRequest: function (data) {
                            //data.ItemTyp = listName + "Item";
                            console.log(someData);
                            return angular.toJson(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution based on lins answer (Thanks!). I set the defaultParams of the $resource based on the parameter of the returned function. In the full code the {a: 1} and {b: 2} are from a model, so that adding the listName there feels dirty.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('mod', ['ngResource']);

    angular.module('mod').controller('Controller', function (ListItem) {
        ListItem({ listName: 'testName' }).save({ a: 1 });
        ListItem().save({ b: 2 });
    });

    angular.module('mod').factory('ListItem', function ($resource) {
        return function (params) {
            var defaultParams = {
                Id: '@Id',
                listName: 'test'
            }
            if (params) {
                angular.forEach(params, function (v, k) {
                    defaultParams[k] = v;
                });
            }
            return $resource('/_api/lists/:listName/:Id', defaultParams, {
                save: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    transformRequest: function (data) {
                        data.ItemTyp = defaultParams.listName + "Item";
                        return angular.toJson(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Answer your own question by input of some other users ... thats not how stackoverflow works :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not know how I should add my solution to this. I mark the answer that helped my to solve this as answer. How cloud I added my solution correctly?

Comment: No need to do this. Everyone can transfer the solution (right answer) to his own codes. Every codes/logic is different, so in my opinion, there is no need for shown a specific solution (your case).

Comment: Okey, thanks for explanation. Will not happen again.

Comment: I find your modification of the solution helpful however